# PEG rules fails to EOI

Tags: rust, peg, pest

I am trying to use PEG expression to take parse the file.
My PEG expression is:

```
WHITESPACE = _{" "}
level = {ASCII_DIGIT*}
verb = {ASCII_ALPHA{,4}}
value = {ASCII_ALPHANUMERIC*}
structure = { level ~ verb ~ value }
file = { SOI ~ (structure? ~ NEWLINE)* ~ EOI }
```

I parse this text:

```
0 HEAD
1 VERB test
2 STOP
```

**file** parse text successfully only, if I have an extra **\n** at the end of the text. If I remove the **\n**, parse fails due to 'expected EOI'. I understood that this happens, because of my rule for **file**. I tried to use different rules for **file** and got infinite loop. So, practically I don't know how to solve this issue. I am using rust and latest pest.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work. It can handle arbitrary number of newlines at the beginning or end as well:

```
file = { SOI ~ NEWLINE* ~ structure ~ (NEWLINE ~ structure)* NEWLINE* ~ EOI }
WHITESPACE = _{" "}
level = {ASCII_DIGIT+}
verb = {ASCII_ALPHA{1,4}}
value = {ASCII_ALPHANUMERIC*}
structure = { level ~ verb ~ value }
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the rules to

```
level = {ASCII_DIGIT+}
verb = {ASCII_ALPHA{1,4}}
file = { SOI ~ (structure? ~ NEWLINE)* ~ structure? ~ EOI }
```

and that seemed to work just fine, regardless of the trailing newline. But maybe I overlooked something. If you could edit your question to show the rules and input that caused an infinite loop with this, that'd be great.

Comment: Does not work.  --> 1:2
  |
1 | 0 HEAD␊
  |  ^---
  |
  = expected verb

Comment: Does work. For the input you provided. I can't pull input out of thin air if you don't provide it.

Answer (score -1):

```
WHITESPACE = _{ " " }
level = {ASCII_DIGIT+}
verb = {ASCII_ALPHA{,4}}
value = {ASCII_ALPHANUMERIC*}
stop = { level ~ "STOP" }
structure = { level ~ verb ~ value }
line = {structure | trlr}
file = { SOI ~ (line ~ NEWLINE?)* ~ EOI }
```

Checked on https://pest.rs/

Comment: You didn't include the definition for `trlr`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).